# How to display datetime interval based on different task?

Tags: php, arrays

How to calculate interval datetime based on each task in this array?

```
$array = [

];
```

I don't know how to use dynamic ways to solve this problem.

```
$interval = $begin->diff($end);
$elapsed  = $interval->format('%y years %m months %a days %h hours %i minutes %s seconds');
echo  $elapsed;
```

Answer (score 2):

What about this?

```
<?php

$array = [
  '2017-02-01T10:00 Task A Start',
  '2017-02-01T10:01 Task A End',
  '2017-02-01T10:08 Task B Start',
  '2017-02-01T20:09 Task C Start',
  '2017-02-01T20:10 Task B End',
  '2017-02-01T20:12 Task C End'
];

$tasks = [];
foreach ($array as $item) {
  $tmp = explode(' ', $item);

  $time = array_shift($tmp);
  $type = array_pop($tmp);
  $name = implode(' ', $tmp);

  $tasks[$name][$type] = $time;
}

foreach ($tasks as $name => $task) {
  $start = new DateTime($task['Start']);
  $end = new DateTime($task['End']);

  $interval = $start->diff($end);
  echo $name.' '.$interval->format('%y years %m months %a days %h hours %i minutes %s seconds')."\n";
}
```

And the output will be

```
Task A 0 years 0 months 0 days 0 hours 1 minutes 0 seconds
Task B 0 years 0 months 0 days 10 hours 2 minutes 0 seconds
Task C 0 years 0 months 0 days 0 hours 3 minutes 0 seconds
```

Answer (score 0):

You can approach this in this way

```
 $array = [
  '2017-02-01T10:00 Task A Start',
  '2017-02-01T10:01 Task A End',
  '2017-02-01T10:08 Task B Start',
  '2017-02-01T20:09 Task C Start',
  '2017-02-01T20:10 Task B End',
  '2017-02-01T20:12 Task C End'
 ];
foreach($array as $v){
  $ex = explode(' ',$v);
  $r[$ex[2]][$ex[3]] = $ex[0];
}
$f = array_map(function($v){
  return gmdate('H:i:s',strtotime($v['End']) - strtotime($v['Start']));//change seconds to H:M:S format
}, $r);
print_r($f);
```

Result :-

```
Array
(
 [A] => 00:01:00
 [B] => 10:02:00
 [C] => 00:03:00
)
```

Working example :- https://3v4l.org/iqu79

Comment: How about avg datetime?

Comment: This will be wrong if the time difference is greater than 24 hours.

Comment: I'm checking solution

Answer (score 0):

A little shorter

```
$input = [
'2017-02-01T10:00 Task A Start',
'2017-02-01T10:01 Task A End',

'2017-02-01T10:08 Task B Start',
'2017-02-01T20:09 Task C Start',
'2017-02-01T20:10 Task B End',
'2017-02-01T20:12 Task C End'
];

$taskArr = [];
foreach($input as $line){
  list($date,,$task,$startEnd) = explode(" ",$line);
  $taskArr[$task][$startEnd] = $date;
}

foreach($taskArr as $key => $task){
  $diff = date_create($task['Start'])
    ->diff(date_create($task['End']))
    ->format(' %y years %m months %a days %h hours %i minutes %s seconds')
  ;
  echo 'Task '.$key.": ".$diff."<br>\n";
}
```

Output:

```
Task A: 0 years 0 months 0 days 0 hours 1 minutes 0 seconds
Task B: 0 years 0 months 0 days 10 hours 2 minutes 0 seconds
Task C: 0 years 0 months 0 days 0 hours 3 minutes 0 seconds
```